Name of artsy italian 60s movie where 2 couples vacation at a shack on the pier
I'm trying to remember the name of a very artsy well shot color foreign film, I think it was Italian, 60s film.  There were some scenes in an industrial factory and many scenes where 2 couples get together in what seems like a shack at a pier for drinking and partying. 
It had beautiful cinematography and some great scenes of industrial imagery and ships as well as just normal life. I seem to remember it had an American actor in it as well that I didn't realize spoke Italian.

The movie was Red Desert by Michaelangelo Antonioni and had Richard Harris.
from imdb-

Cold, rain, and fog surround a plant in Ravenna. Factory waste
  pollutes local lakes; hulking anonymous ships pass or dock and raise
  quarantine flags. Guiliana, a housewife married to the plant manager,
  Ugo, is mentally ill, hiding it from her husband as best she can. She
  meets Zeller, an engineer en route to Patagonia to set up a factory.
  He pursues her, they join friends for a dinner party of sexual play,
  then, while Ugo is away on business, she fears that her son has polio.
  When she discovers the boy is faking, she goes to Zeller, panicked
  that no one needs her. He takes advantage of her distress, and she is
  again alone and ill.

summary by jhailey@hotmail.com
